# Need a Recursive Function to Solve a Typical Ecommerce Multi-Variation Problem

Tags: c#, recursion, e-commerce

Let's say I have the following data (in pseudo-code for readability):

```
var myVariations = [
    { Name = "Color", Values = ["Red", "Yellow", "Green" /*, etc. */] },
    { Name = "Size", Values = ["S", "M", "L" /*, etc. */] },
    { Name = "Length", Values = ["34", "35", "36" /*, etc. */] },
    /* and so on...(up to 5 total) */
];
```

And I can get that data with LINQ like so:

```
var myVariations = myProduct.Variations.ToList();
```

**How can I go about mapping those variations into a structure like this (for the eBay Trading API):**

```
var ebayVariations = [
    {
        Name = "Red-S-34",
        Value = [
                                       // yes, these are arrays with only one item
            { Name = "Color", Values = [{Value = "Red"}] },
            { Name = "Size", Values = [{Value = "S"}] },
            { Name = "Length", Values = [{Value = "34" }] }
        ]
    },
    /* etc for all possible combinations */
];
```

Obviously the fact that the `Values` array holds only one value is a bit strange; but with eBay's Trading API if I list multiple values in a single Variation (which is easy to do compared to this recursive stuff) it complains. **So alternatively, if you are familiar with the eBay Trading API, how can I get this to work in an "optimal" fashion, in-line with the way eBay intended Variations to be listed** (called via AddFixedPricedItem, if you care).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the eBay Trading API, but [here's an article on computing a Cartesian Product with LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) (the very last step drops the recursion in favor of aggregation).

Comment: I can't figure out how to fit my Variant model into the CartesianProduct method.

Comment: Did you get it worked out? I had started on an implementation for you and then got called into a meeting. Sorry about that, but I hope it's working.

Comment: Well, I got it "hacked" out. I ended up with *string* results like: "Color=White,Size=S,Length=36" and "Color=White,Size=S,Length=38", etc...I couldn't figure out how to maintain the *object* structure. So before passing the objects to the CartesianProduct function I concatenated the Names and Values to strings; basically: `variations.Select(v => v.Values.Select(a => v.Name + "=" + a.Value))` (my actual implementation has some additional metadata for the Values which is why they are an object, not an array here). I'm still working on it and will most likely accept this answer. Thanks and +1!

Answer (score 1):

I've changed terminology insignificantly, but wrote clarifying comments.

```
    public IEnumerable<Combination> GetCombinations(Variation[] variations, int variationIndex, IEnumerable<VariationPosition> aggregatedPositions)
    {
        // We should choose one position from every variation, 
        // so we couldn't produce combination till we reach end of array. 
        if (variationIndex < variations.Length)
        {
            // Pick current variation.  
            var currentVariation = variations[variationIndex];

            // Every variation has list of possible positions (Color could be Green, Redm, Blue, etc.).
            // So we should walk through all the positions 
            foreach (var val in currentVariation.Positions)
            {
                // Current position. Variation's name will be used during creating result Combination.
                var position = new VariationPosition()
                {
                    Name = currentVariation.Name,
                    Value = val
                };
                // Add position to already aggregated on upper levels of recursion positions.
                var newPositions = aggregatedPositions.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(position, 1));

                // So we picked some variation position 
                // Let's go deeper.
                var combinations = this.GetCombinations(variations, variationIndex + 1, newPositions );

                // This piece of code allows us return combinations in iterator fashion.
                foreach (var combination in combinations)
                {
                    yield return combination;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // We reached end of variations array 
            // I mean we have one position of every variation. 

            // We concatenate name of positions in order to create string like "Red-S-34"
            var name = aggregatedPositions.Aggregate("", (res, v) => res += v.Name);

            // This code is a little bit naive, I'm too lazy to create proper infrastructure,
            // But its mission is to create content for property Value of your ebayVariations item. 
            var value = aggregatedPositions
                .Select(v => new { Name = v.Name, Values = new[] { new { Value = v.Value } } })
                .ToArray();

            // And we return completed combination.
            yield return new Combination()
            {
                Name = name,
                Value = value,
            };
        }
    }
```

And usage:

```
var allCombinations = this.GetCombinations(inputVariations, 0, new VariationPosition[0]).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1. I've already implemented a hacky version of a the Linq/CartesianProduct method. I'm spending too much time on this right now but I'll come back to your answer later to see if it will be a better fit.

Comment: @alex sashok  was wondering if you can help out wtih this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929259/ebay-api-returning-auctions-ending-later-than-10-days